# Odd Errors for Python installation library

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, installation

I am trying to install MatPlotlib.org for my Python program. More specifically trying to do what this guy is doing here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6gvtfQHJUs&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfpEcGUM6ogsbrlWtqpS5-1&index=22

I've installed the 32bit windows 7 version which went smoothly for the installation process as I am using Python 32 bit. The problem is when I get to the part in the video where he imports the basemap. I am getting an error saying:

```
"from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from matplotlib import __version__ as _matplotlib_version
ImportError: No module named matplotlib"
```

I've been trying to solve this for a while, but can't get anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add matplotlib to your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: That's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: So would I add "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits" to my path?

Comment: You need to add the directory which contains `__init__.py`

Comment: my mpl_toolkits folder has "basemap", "__init__".py and 2 other __init__.compiled python folders. I've added the pythonpaths, but it's still giving the same error...